# run a target always along with default target

Tags: makefile

I have a default target "all" but I want to initialize a few variables ever time I run the makefile . whatever is the target for make flow.

cat Makefile

```
all: last_step 

initialize:  
 ifeq (,$(filter $(ps),0 1)) 
 @$(eval override ps=0) 
 endif 

step1:  
 <> 
step2: step1 
 <> 
....  
last_step: second_last_step 
 <>
```

I want to initialize the variable every time a make file is run .
initialize target should be run in both the following flow styles.

make .

make nth-step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing easier:

```
ifeq (,$(filter $(ps),0 1)) 
override ps=0
endif 

all: last_step 
    ...

step1:  
    ...

...
```